# How to extract some image from text with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

Hey people how can I extract an image from text like this:

`bla bla bla bl [IMG2;DanilaCarneiro_capa2.jpg;D], bla bla bla , [IMG2;abcsd.jpg;E], bla bla`

What I did:

`preg_match_all('![IMG2;[a-z0-9\-\.\/]+\.(?:jpeg|png|gif)!Ui' , $value->CORPO , $matches);`

but it just give the last name for example `DanilaCarneiro_capa2.jpg` give -> `capa2.jpg`, i need
`DanilaCarneiro_capa2.jpg` and this `[IMG2;DanilaCarneiro_capa2.jpg;D]`.

Is very difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('!\[IMG2;(.*?(?:jpg|png|gif))!i', $value->CORPO , $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\[IMG2;\K[^];]++~i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $value->CORPO, $matches);
```

If you want to check the extension:

```
$pattern = '~\[IMG2;\K[^];]+\.(?:jpeg|png|gif)(?=[];])~i';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to escape the square bracket

```
 \[IMG2;[a-z0-9\-./]+\.(?:jpeg|png|gif)
```